# Formatting NumberInput with React-Admin: best practices

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

What is the best way to format numbers on a `NumberInput` using React Admin?

With the [examples](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#recipes) on the docs we've tried this:

```js
<NumberInput
    source="price"
    format={(v: number) => Number(v).toFixed(2)}
/>
```

It looks nice enough but the editing does not work well. What's the "official" suggestion for this feature? Use a JS library? Some React component? Is there an example somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "edit does not work well ?"

Maybe it is because "v" is not always a number, but a string ? You'd maybe better to `Number.parseFloat(v).toFixed(2)` to be sure ?

Comment: It does not work either. After a value is typed you cant delete with backspace nor use the caret to edit the value.

Comment: toFixed(2) converts the number to a string, so maybe add the "parse" props to do the opposite ? I.e. parse={v => parseFloat(v)}

Comment: Not working yet, but thanks anyway.